# I want to make a voltage limiting circuit

Tags: voltage, transistors

I want to make a simple circuit that gives a constant output voltage regardless of tiny fluctuations in the input. Is it possible to make it so that when the input is off, the output is off, but when it is on the output is Vcc? I tried some configurations using BJTs (BC547B) but there are always fluctuations in the output.

[image]

Comment: It is, unless the specifications you require are impossible. So your specific case can't be answered without knowing what you want to do and why.

Comment: Hook an appropriate relay coil between vin and ground. Hook vcc to one side of the relay's normally-open switch. Hook vout to the other side of the relay's switch. Done.

Comment: In engineering, try to avoid words like "tiny" and instead specify what counts as big or small.  In your particular case, to solve the problem you need to know the input voltages, the output current, how much variation there is in the input, and how much variation is permitted in the output.  Don't answer "none" or your circuit won't be possible!

Comment: How does what you want differ from a common voltage regulator circuit?

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to make a simple circuit that gives a constant output voltage
> regardless of tiny fluctuations in the input.*

Unless you are at [absolute zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero) (a temperature of -273.15°C), there will always be fluctuations on the input signal. So, given that there will always be fluctuations and you want the output to be "on" under these circumstances, connect the output directly with Vcc. No need to monitor the input signal at all because there will always be fluctuations. Just monitor the temperature. When the temperature reaches absolute zero, turn the output signal off.